# CORS error when reading video from canvas (tainted canvas)

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-video, cors

I'm running an HLS stream that I want to write to a canvas; and then read pixels from the canvas.

The video gets rendered to the canvas A-ok, but it gets kicked off at:

`myPixel = c.getImageData(200, 200, 1, 1).data;`

where it fails with:

`[Error] SecurityError: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.`

`[Error] Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.`

I've set the cross-domain settings on the Wowza streaming server to:

```
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="false"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/>
```

and `crossOrigin="anonymous"` on the client side video element.

It works and fails with different computers on the same network, all running Safari 7.0.2/Mac.

Any good ideas for debugging this?

Comment: What does the network part in the console say about mime types (response header) for the video? Do you also see the Access-Control* headers?

Comment: Nope - I don't explicitly seem to receive the Access-Control-headers on the stream. The full header, as far as I can see is: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`
`Date: Thu, 13 Mar 2014 12:33:12 GMT`
`Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.mpegurl`
`Accept-Ranges: bytes`
`Server: FlashCom/3.5.7`
`Cache-Control: no-cache`
`Content-Length: 152`

Answer (score 0):

If your modifications work on some computers and not on other identically configured computers, try clearing the cache on the misbehaving computers.

Force a reload on the misbehaving macs like this:

Hold `Shift` and `Cmd` and press `R`.